# Filter Array of mail threads by label

Tags: filter, gmail, label, indexof

**Goal: get an array of threads from gmail that fulfills filter criteria**:

thread must have label "new" that is nested under label "Status"
thread must not have label "open" that is nested under label "Status"

**Failed attempt:**
var threads_new = GmailApp.search('label:Status-new -label:Status-open'); gives me the same as:
var threads_new = GmailApp.search('label:Status-new) So "Status/open" was not sorted out.

**New approach:**
I want to first load all mail threads with label "new" as array "threads_new" and then create a new array "threads_new_closed" that does not contain label "open":

var threads_new_closed = threads_new_closed.filter(function(thread) {
return thread.getLabels().indexOf("Status/open")!=-1});

Wrong result: The result is an empty array threads_new_closed (values with Status/new and without Status/open do exist in array threas_new)

Any Idea? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I found the following workaround:

```
var threads_new_closed = [];
for (var k = threads_new.length - 1; k >=0; k--) {
var exclude = 0;
var thread_labels = threads_new[k].getLabels()
for (var l = threads_new[k].getLabels().length - 1; l >=0; l--) {
if (thread_labels[l].getName().indexOf("Status/open") != -1) {exclude++};
}
if (exclude == 0) {
threads_new_closed.push(threads_new[k])
}
```